# In C++ when a function returns an object by value, at the call point should a copy constructor be called

Tags: c++

I am executing the following code C++ code on

> (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609

```
class x {
    public :
    int data ;
    x(int v) {cout<<"1 args constr\n" ; data = v ;}
    x(const x& o) {cout<<"copy constr\n" ;}
    x &operator=(const x&o) {cout<<"assignment opr\n" ;}
    ~x() {cout<<"destr\n" ;}
} ;

x fun() {
    cout<<"in func\n" ;   //#1
    x o(-19) ;            //#2
    cout<<"returning...\n";
    return o ;            //#3
}

main() {
    x ob = fun() ;        //#4
    cout<<ob.data<<endl ;
}
```

And getting the following output:
    in func
    1 args constr
    returning...
    -19
    destr

What I am not able to understand is :

1. why are the constructor and destructor called ony once
2. why is the copy constructor not invoked when I am returning by value

As per my understanding, `ob` is created in the scope of `main`. Thus the constructor and destructor for `ob` should be called in the scope of `main`.
Likewise, `o` is created in the scope of `fun`. And thus there should be one constructor and destructor invocation for `o` in the scope of `fun`

Comment: x &operator=(const x&o) {cout<<"assignment opr\n" ;}
 bug here fix the operator overloading definition

Comment: Read about the [rule of five](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Comment: @ Basile Starynkevitch I am not compiling code for C++11. Even after adding the move semantics and compiling for C++11 I am getting the same output

Comment: The explanation of what you are seeing is copy elision or return value optimisation.     Although you haven't asked what they are, I've marked this as a duplicate of a question asking about them - the answers to that question explain the type of effect you are seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ compiler is doing the return value optimization once compiled. Note return value optimization can't be done if any of the end-points of a function return the different named local variable. In your case, there is only end-point for the function(return statement). So C++ compiler performs a Return Value Optimization.
Check this out: [return_value_optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization)